# Can I deploy an Angular App to an already existing WebAPI app in Azure?

Tags: .net, angular, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing WebAPI application hosted on Azure. It provides a simple endpoint and cache for my Angular application to connect to. Can I simply deploy to this same app on Azure and it contains both my Angular app as well as my Web API backend? I'm totally new to Azure and deployment in general and I haven't been able to find an answer to this problem (having built these two applications separately, but needing them deployed "together").

If this isn't the correct way to do this, can someone explain or point me towards a resource of how to go about this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can most definitely do this. In fact, it's a popular/useful configuration b/c it allows the Web API to enforce CORS rules to restrict access to only same-domain callers (i.e. your Angular SPA app).

Add the Angular app entry-point file (index htm/js, or whatever), along with the JS files (and other assets) for the app, in a subfolder under wwwroot. Put the source (JS, ts, etc.) files for your Angular app in a project subfolder (outside of wwwroot), and direct the build system (i.e. webpack or similar) to output to the subfolder in wwwroot. Uou might also want to configure your ASP.NET app to allow for hot reload and pre-rendering, but those are optonal (but desirable) optimizations.

Lastly, there's no difference between doing this in a "new" project vs. an existing, deployed app.

Answer (score 0):

If your WebAPI is able to host your Angular app, then there is no problem with that. But a better idea is to have your Angular App (I assume it's SPA) have deployed on (for example) static hosting. It's faster and cheaper. For example, you can deploy it to [Azure Blob Storage as a static webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)